# Selecting Last line of Text Area

Tags: java, swing, text, textarea

I am trying to create a java text area, with it being created with the text 
"Chat Here!" being placed inside the textarea. I then want them to type in a word, and press enter. When they press enter, i want to be able to select the text from just that line - (i.e. chatArea.getText() gets all the text, including the "Chat Here!", which is not what I want. As well, I can't say that the text they enter will always be on a specific line (i.e. always the 2nd line); I haven't found a way to access the line the user has put in exclusively yet. Any help would really be appreciated. I'm still new to java, so if examples of code could be given as well, that'd be really helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've tried the .getText() method, and working with that for a half hour, but don't know how to get any further. I'm really lost in this code.

Comment: Post the relevant code excerpt, so people here can take a look at it and suggest appropriate solutions. No code, no answer !

Comment: If you can get all the content of your text, then split it by "\n" and then use the last line.

Comment: Or, find the lastIndexof("\n") and then substring() it to the end of your text.

Answer (score 1):

> I then want them to type in a word, and press enter. When they press enter, i want to be able to select the text from just that line

You can use the `Utilities` class to help you out:

```
int end = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
int start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);

while (start == end)
{
    end--;
    start = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, end);
}

String text = textArea.getText(start, end - start);
System.out.println("(" + text + ")");
```

The above will return the last line that contains text. The while loop handles empty lines at the end of the text area.